# adding element of a list to a column of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have defined such a dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
schema = StructType([
    StructField("date", StringType(), True), StructField("amount", StringType(), False), StructField("fontred", StringType(), False)
])
```

and I have such a list:

```
Elements=['01.07.', '01.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.']
```

How can I add elements of this list to first column of dataframe?

```
date      amount  fontred
----------------------------
01.07.
01.07.
02.07.
02.07.
02.07.
02.07.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've confused the nullable parameter... I've changed it for you. See if the code below is what you want:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("date", StringType(), False),
    StructField("amount", StringType(), True),
    StructField("fontred", StringType(), True)
])

Elements = ['01.07.', '01.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.']

df = spark.createDataFrame([[i,None,None] for i in Elements], schema=schema)

df.show()
+------+------+-------+
|  date|amount|fontred|
+------+------+-------+
|01.07.|  null|   null|
|01.07.|  null|   null|
|02.07.|  null|   null|
|02.07.|  null|   null|
|02.07.|  null|   null|
|02.07.|  null|   null|
+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, if use your logic for `amount`  -> `column: df = spark.createDataFrame([[None,i,None] for i in Elements], schema=schema)` then I loose information in date column. do you have any Idea what should i do?

Comment: If you have multiple columns that you want to combine, you can do, for example, `df = spark.createDataFrame([[i,j,None] for i,j in zip(Elements,AnotherElements)], schema=schema)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pandas` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Elements = ['01.07.', '01.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.', '02.07.']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': Elements})
df['amount'] = df['fontred'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     date  amount  fontred
0  01.07.     NaN      NaN
1  01.07.     NaN      NaN
2  02.07.     NaN      NaN
3  02.07.     NaN      NaN
4  02.07.     NaN      NaN
5  02.07.     NaN      NaN
```